# For loop with two variables in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following java code:

```
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10 && j < 10 0; i++, j++)
  {
           System.out.println("i = " + i + " :: " + "j = " + j);

  }
```

The output is :

```
i = 0 :: j = 0
i = 1 :: j = 1
i = 2 :: j = 2
i = 3 :: j = 3
i = 4 :: j = 4
i = 5 :: j = 5
....
```

I would like to do the same thing in scala, I tried this but it does not work:

```
for (i<- 0 to 9; j <- 0 to 9) 
{
     println("i = " + i + " :: " + "j = " + j) 
 }
```

The output is:

```
i = 0 :: j = 0
i = 0 :: j = 1
i = 0 :: j = 2
i = 0 :: j = 3
i = 0 :: j = 4
i = 0 :: j = 5
i = 0 :: j = 6
i = 0 :: j = 7
i = 0 :: j = 8
i = 0 :: j = 9
i = 1 :: j = 0
i = 1 :: j = 1
i = 1 :: j = 2
i = 1 :: j = 3
....
```

I have not find a way to have two variables in the same level.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If both values will have the same value, what is even the point of having two? What exactly do you want to solve? BTW, **Scala** doesn't have for loops, it has for comprehensions, there is no mutation involved at all.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't think it's about literally having two identical values. I'd guess it's about the principle of iterating over two variables at once. And it can be done either with `for` and a custom structure or a `while` loop with less sexy syntax (var i, var j, while(...) {... i+=1; j+=1}

Comment: `for` in Scala is _not_ a for-loop from Java. In some cases the behavior might be similar but one cannot be brainlessly substituted for another.

Comment: @Nebril, yes you are right. it's about the principle of iterating over two variables at once.How can I do that in scala ?

Comment: @Nebril the point is one doesn't iterate values in functional programming, as such two values having the same value are the same thing. That is why I ask what exactly is the problem OP wants to solve instead of focus in the technique.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ok, so I share with you the problem I want to solve.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  I have shared the problem in the following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972252/how-to-substract-two-consecutive-element-in-a-list-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both variables always have the same value, you actually only need one of them. In Scala, you would generally *not* use a loop to solve this problem, but use higher-level collection operations instead. Something like:

```scala
(0 to 9) map { i => s"i = $i :: j = $i" } mkString "\n"
```

Note: this will only generate the string that you want to print, but not actually print it. It is generally considered a good thing to not mix *generating* data and *printing* data.

If you want to print this, you only need to pass it to `println`:

```scala
println((0 to 9) map { i => s"i = $i :: j = $i" } mkString "\n")
```

Or, in Scala 2.13+:

```scala
import scala.util.chaining._

(0 to 9) map { i => s"i = $i :: j = $i" } mkString "\n" pipe println
```

You *could* also write it like this:

```scala
(for (i <- 0 to 9) yield s"i = $i :: j = $i") mkString "\n"
```

Now, you might say, "Wait a minute, didn't you just say that we don't use loops in Scala?" Well, here's the thing: that's not a loop! That is a *`for` comprehension*. It is actually syntactic sugar for collection operations.

```scala
for (foo <- bar) yield baz(foo)
```

is actually just syntactic sugar for

```scala
bar map { foo => baz(foo) }
```

A `for` comprehension simply desugars into calls to `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, and `withFilter`. It is *not* a loop.

Note that Scala *does* have a `while` loop. It exists mainly for performance reasons. Unless you are writing low-level libraries that are going to be used in performance-intensive code by tens of thousands of developers, please just pretend that it doesn't exist.

Also note that if the `while` loop weren't built into Scala, you could easily write it yourself:

```scala
def whiley(cond: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit =
  if (cond) { body; whiley(cond)(body) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Scala's replacement would be

```
for {
  (i, j) <- (0 to 9) zip (0 to 9)
} {
  println("i = " + i + " :: " + "j = " + j) 
}
```

To avoid the confusion I suggest reading what `for` is the syntactic sugar for (as opposed to Java it is not specialized `while`).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as below

```
val start = 0; val size = 10;
for ((i, j) <- (start to size) zip (start to size))
 {
  println(s"i=$i j=$j")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`j` is just a copy of `i` so this is one solution:

```
for {
  i <- 0 to 9
  j = i
} {
  println("i = " + i + " :: " + "j = " + j) 
}
```

This pattern works in any situation where `j` is just a function of `i`